# Use of Condition in Mapping Node in IIB v9

Tags: mapping, xslt-2.0, messagebroker

I am trying to use a mapping node in the flow to map data from one xml to other.
I can achieve it in e-sql but due to some constraints can't use it.
 Mapping if like

COST ------------------(Condition)-------------------------------->FLAG

```
CONDITION:

if cost=10 then
Flag =y
else if cost=11
Flag =n
```

I have tried to use IF in the mapping but unable to figure out how to use it here.
How can this condition be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to the above problem is to use condition with assign.
Select 'if' in the mapping it will direct you to the sub flow where you can ASSIGN the value as required.